# Windows Service hosting WCF service can only be accessed by my domain user

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I had developed a windows service that hosts a WCF service. The service is installed on a server and the idea is to process some files on the local network (domain). Also, the service is executing as my domain user.

the configuration of the service is this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Zeus.My.Upload.Service.MyHostedService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1089/Domain/Service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1089/Domain/Service/Uploader" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Zeus.My.Upload.Contract.IHostedService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967296" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="01:00:00" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The issue with this configuration is that only my user is able to access and use this service. Other users of domain cannot even access to the URL.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you check firewall rules?

Comment: Hi @pepo, not really. I realized that only my user can access this service on the network. So I think I will impersonate the usage of the service.